# What is this flat metallic component?

Tags: identification

What is the metallic component, labeled Y1, just at the right of the integrated circuit and at the left of the small C4 and C5 capacitors?

When I search for “N24.000” on Google, I find only other boards with the same component, but no information about the component itself.

If I search for “electronic component N24,” all I find are references to a bipolar transistor, however the component has only two connectors and therefore is not a transistor.

Searching for “7C20PF” doesn't give anything useful either.

[image]

Comment: Besides the obvious answer, what is this board?
I see the serial port connector and VCC terminals.
The rest I'm assuming are lots of inputs and outputs.
What type of sensors was this expecting?
I'm always on the lookout for another data logger.

Comment: @Arseni looks like a servo motor Control board. Not the same, but looks similar: https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32813133679.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What is the metallic component, labeled Y1, just at the right of the integrated circuit and at the left of the small C4 and C5 capacitors?

It is a 24 MHz crystal (hence the "24.000" marking on the top).

The component designator letter "Y" is commonly used for crystals.

Capacitors C4 and C5 will be the load capacitors for the crystal.

Comment: C4&C5, poor component placement. Should be between the crystal and the µC.

Comment: at 24Mhz that's unlikely to make a measurable difference,

Comment: @Jasen Just curious. Around what frequency does it start to be of a concern?

Comment: @PNDA The general rule of thumb I hear is that traces shorter than 1/10 of a wavelength don't really matter. That would be about 60cm (assuming the signal travels at half of light speed).

Comment: 60 or even 6cm would probably create parasitic capacitance more than the 20pf load required for the crystal. And PCB track is not a very good capacitor for a timing circuit.

Answer (score 11):

It is a clock crystal as part of the MCU clock circuit . That is also common for reference designators "Y"

24.000 indicates frequency 
20pf indicates loading

C4 and C5 are capacitors used as part of the oscillator circuit.

Comment: That's a little surprising. In undergrad EE classes, crystal oscillators were usually labelled either as XTAL or simply X. So why switch that over to Y?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya generation Y took over. IEEE 315 has it in it's list like this with Y. And the PDF looked like really old (1975), but there are other standards around and lot's of personal preference.

Comment: @PradyothShandilya perhaps to disambiguate between crystal (Y) and Crystal oscillator (XO)